# How to check if music/movie/game is playing in the foreground?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-10.0

I'm trying to identify what is the current audio usage for. I need to know if it is for music, movie, or game.

So far, this is how I'm trying to get the information from the AudioAttribute class but I don't get the expected results. Most of the time I get `type=CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC` even if I'm playing a movie using the PrimeVideo app or I get `usage=USAGE_MEDIA` while playing a game.

```html
List<AudioPlaybackConfiguration> configs = mAudioManager.getActivePlaybackConfigurations();

AudioPlaybackConfiguration config = configs.get(0);
int type = config.getAudioAttributes().getContentType();
int usage = config.getAudioAttributes().getUsage();
```

I would like to know if there any way to get this information even if I need to use a hidden method or installing the app in system/app

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP

Comment: hi, I'm wondering to know did you solve this problem yet and how did you make this done ?